# DefaultListModel.clear errors

Tags: java, swing, runtime-error

I'm trying to display a list of items and, when the user clicks on an item, to clear the list and display another list.

If I run this and click on the first entry on the displayed list, the program dies with a long trail of runtime exceptions.  If I remove the clear() line (commented below), it runs fine. Adding try/catch didn't reveal any information useful to me.  Apologies for the long code, but I couldn't figure out how to shorten and still generate the errors.

What at I doing wrong?

```
import java.util.*;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;

class ListGui extends JPanel implements ListSelectionListener {

    private static JList list;
    private static DefaultListModel listModel = new DefaultListModel();

    public ListGui() {
        super(new BorderLayout());
        list = new JList(listModel);
        list.setSelectionMode(ListSelectionModel.SINGLE_SELECTION);
        list.addListSelectionListener(this);
        JScrollPane listScrollPane = new JScrollPane(list);
        add(listScrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public static void Populate(List<String> lines) {
        listModel.clear();
        for(String line : lines) {
            listModel.addElement(line);
        }
    }

    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false) {
            List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
            out.add("three");
            out.add("four");
            Populate(out);
        }
    } 
}

public class TestClear {

    static JComponent newContentPane = new ListGui();

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("toast");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);       
        frame.setContentPane(newContentPane);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) { 

        List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();

        createAndShowGUI();

        out.add("one");
        out.add("two");
        ListGui.Populate(out);               
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the exception thrown please?

Comment: When I ran my original code, the exception was "-1"  I'm this running this shortened version from a windows command line which only captures about 100 lines and it's scrolling off the screen.  What's the best way to record?

Comment: Use command redirection to write the console output or error stream to a file: see http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/redirection.mspx

Answer (score 3):

> I'm trying to display a list of items and, when the user clicks on an item, to clear the list and display another list.

That doesn't sound like the best design to me. The selection will change whenever you click on an item or when you use the arrow keys to move up or down the list. I'm sure for users that like to use the keyboard you don't want the list to change every time you use an arrow key.

The normal design would be to invoke an Action on the list on a "double click" or when the user users "Enter" from the keboard. This is easily implemente using the [List Action](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/14/list-action/) concept.

However, if you really do want to update the list on every selection then I would use code like:

```
list.removeListSelectionListener( this );
populate(...);
list.addListSelectionListener(this);
```

Comment: Invoking an action on double click or enter is on my to do list.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are calling Populate() in valueChanged() which triggers valueChanged() and hence the stackoverflow.

The simplest solution is to have a flag to prevent reentry.

```
 boolean busy = false;
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {

        if (e.getValueIsAdjusting() == false && !busy) {
            busy = true;
            List<String> out = new ArrayList<String>();
            out.add("three");
            out.add("four");
            Populate(out);
            busy = false;
        }
    }
```

If your code could be accessed by multiple threads, you should be looking into [ReentrantLock](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantLock.html)

Comment: That makes sense, but why would it only die when I click on the first element and not die when I remove clear?  I'll try the busy flag and report back.

Comment: Yep, that works. I hadn't realized the program changing the list would trigger valueChanged().

Comment: My two cents worth. I don't like the "busy flag" approach because now you have code in three different places in your class. 1) you need to define the variable, 2) you need to reset it in the valueChanged() method and 3) you need to test it in the populate() method.

Comment: I'm more or less indifferent between the two approaches.  Removing and adding back the listener isn't that much less effort than removing and setting a busy flag.  Would adding a listener be a more "expensive" activity than just setting a variable?  It seems closer to an OS operation, which typically takes more resources.

Comment: The comment is about maintenance of the code. Its easier to maintain and understand code when all the logic for a given piece of functionality is contained in one place rather than trying to track it down over 3 different places to find out where/when the boolen variable is set and reset. In general boolean variables should be avoided if possible when the related functionality is contained in multiple different methods.

Comment: It's clearly easier to maintain when everything is in one place, but that doesn't seem to apply here.  The flag is set and reset within a few lines, and could be rewritten to just surround the one line Populate()